# How to make a tuple with a sequence from sequence of tuples?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a collection of tuples:

```
Seq(("foo", "bar3"), ("foo", "bar1"), ("foo", "bar2"))
```

How do I apply such a function that I get

```
("foo", Seq("bar1", "bar2", "bar3"))
```

I just cannot wrap my head around this. I am new to functional programming so I was thinking about some sort of folding or aggregating.

Comment: Will the first element of the tuple always have the same value? Or do you want to collect together all the second elements that share the same value of the first element? And is the order of the Seq of second elements important? I note it isn't the order of the input sequence, and is sorted, but is that accidental or do you want it sorted?

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul The order is not important. I want to collect together all the second elements that share the same value of the first element.

Comment: Thanks. Sergey's answer is a good 'un, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your solution looks like this:

```
val seq = Seq(("foo", "bar3"), ("foo", "bar1"), ("foo", "bar2"))
seq.groupBy(_._1)
  .mapValues(_.map(_._2))
```

Comment: @AlexandrDorokhin partially I agree with you. Made minor improvements in code

Comment: @AlexandrDorokhin

But it works well, even with structure like `Seq((foo, foo1, bar1),(foo, foo1, bar2),...` (with replacing `_._2` in the last line of code with custom mapping.